# Avoiding repeatition of data in html table created using freeMarker Template

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I am using FreeMarker template to generate an html table. The data comes from server as `List<List<Object>>` in a `POJO`.

I am creating the table using following code (as of now)

```
<#if report.getFormattedRecord()?has_content>
    <#assign allRows = report.getFormattedRecord()>
</#if>

<table>
    <#if allRows ??>
        <#list allRows as rowEntry>
            <tr>
                <#list rowEntry as cellEntry>
                        <#if cellEntry ??>
                            <td nowrap style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10" align=${columnStyle(columnType[cellEntry_index])}>${cellEntry}</td>
                        <#else>
                            <td> </td>
                        </#if>
                </#list>
            </tr>
        </#list>                    
    <#else>
        <tr>
            <td>No records found</td>
        </tr>
    </#if>          
</table>
```

But, this generates output as follow-

[image: The output with current code]

But, i want output like following (To avoid redundant data)

[image: Expected]

(Generated by hardcoding the html.)

How can i process the input to generate such output.

The problems i am facing are-

1) Data is not sorted as of now

2) I do not know the number of columns for which values are repeated

3) Parsing the data return to create such HTML using freemarker templates

Is there any better design possible for avoiding redundancy?

Thanks

Comment: For starting, we can assume `Data is sorted` in all 3 columns, which have repeated entries. But, 2 and 3 are mandatory for me

Comment: Can this be done by changing format of data received from server? I think, `Map` can be used. It should make my task easier, but i am not getting `what can be the format for Map`, and then `Is parsing the Map will be easy in freemarker (ftl)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soring shouldn't done in FTL usually, instead the Model should contain the data already sorted. This part is just MVC good practice.

As of making the td rowspan-s, for the sake of this discussion first let's assume you solve it in the Model (the "data model" with FreeMarker terminology). Then all you need is a `cellHeight` property for each cell: It tells you the `rowspan` attribute value, or if it's `0`, that means you should skip displaying that cell.

But certainly you don't want to pollute the Model with such View detail. So you could maintain an FTL variable for each column where you want to do this spanning, let's call it `cellHeightLeft`. Its initial value should be `0`. When it comes to printing a `td`, you check its vale. If it's `0`, then you do a look ahead using indexed access (`allRows[someIndex][someCol]`) to count how long this span will be, store that in `cellHeightLeft`, print the `td` with the `rowspan` attribute value, then decrease `cellHeightLeft`. If it's non-0, you skip the `td`, and decrease `cellHeightLeft`. So that's the basic algorithm. You may will need some `#function`-s and such to do this nicely.

Comment: I understood the algo, so accepted it. But stuck at `You could maintain an FTL variable for each column`. :( How to do this?

Comment: With this approach, for data like `A B1 C` and `A B2 C`, C will be grouped, which looks a bit bad, i need something like if previous column is not grouped, do not group this as well as all the child columns

Comment: If you know ahead what columns you will have, each can have its own dedicated variable. If you want to solve it for some more generic case, I would advise calling out to Java `TemplateMethodModelEx`, for transforming the model a bit... FTL is not meant to be used for implementing complex algorithms.

Comment: As of the `A B1 C` `A B2 C` problem, of course then then the look ahead will have to consider the columns left to the investigated columns.

Comment: Forgot to mention... `TemplateMethodModelEx`-es can be instantiated from FTL like `<#assign myHelper='com.example.MyHelper'?new()>` and then called to do the heavy lifting, like `myHelper(params)`.

Comment: I implemented the algorithm with lookahead in FTL. Its working absolutely fine :) But, FTL does not suppose to do this. I will try to use `TemplateMethodModelEx`. Thanks